# scons: multiple files as a target

Tags: scons

I have a script, lets say "foo.py", which depends on some file, let's say "dep.par", and I would call these as

```
python foo.py --parameters=dep.par
```

If foo.py writes only one output file, "bar.dat", I would say:

```
env=Environment()
env.Command("bar.dat", "dep.par", "python foo.py --parameters=dep.par")
```

However, I need the case where foo.py outputs more than one file, let's say "bar1.dat, bar2.dat, ..., barN.dat".

I'm at a loss, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target (and/or source) can be a list of targets as follows:

```
env=Environment()
env.Command(["bar1.dat", "bar2.dat"], "dep.par", "python foo.py --parameters=dep.par")
```

Comment: excellent, thanks. I though I had tried that; anyways it works now. thanks again.

Comment: What if the target is a variable length file list?

Comment: @yegle that will work, like i mentioned the target can be a list.

Comment: @Brady This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397676/scons-how-to-deal-with-dynamic-targets Some command will produce variable length file list like `convert` do and I'm not sure how to specify target in this situation.

Comment: `env.Command(["bar1.dat", "bar2.dat"], "dep.par", "python foo.py --parameters=$SOURCE"` is probably a little clearer in that you don't have to duplicate dep.par.  There's also $TARGET and $TARGETS